# Do I have $\phi(a^*)=\overline{\phi(a)}$ for $\phi$ a State on a C*-Algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the following correct or am I confused about something?

> $\phi(x^*)=\overline{\phi(x)}$ for $x\in A$ and $\phi\in S(A)$.

Let $x\in A$, a C*-algebra. I can write 
$$x=a-b+ic-id,$$
where $a,\,b,\,c,\,d\in A_+$.

Now suppose $\phi$ is a positive linear functional. We have

$$\begin{align}
\phi(x)&=\phi(a)-\phi(b)+i\phi(c)-i\phi(d)
\\ \Rightarrow \overline{\phi(x)}&=\phi(a)-\phi(b)-i\phi(c)+i\phi(d).
\end{align}$$
However we have
$$x^*=a-b-ic+id\Rightarrow \phi(x^*)=\phi(a)-\phi(b)-i\phi(c)+i\phi(d)=\overline{\phi(x)},$$

i.e. $\phi(x^*)=\overline{\phi(x)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, the only remark that I can have is that you could wirte it in a bit more details.

Let us start with a selfadjoint element $x \in A$, when we can write $x = x_{+}- x_{-}$, where $x_{+}=f(x)$ (with $f(t) = \max(0,t)$) and $x_{-}=-g(x)$ (with $g(t) = \min(0,t)$) are positive elements of $A$. Thus, 
$$ \phi(x) = \phi(x_+) - \phi(x_{-}) \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Now we know that we can write an arbitrary element $a$ of a C*-algebra as
$$a = \mathrm{Re}(a) + i\mathrm{Im}(a) ,$$
where $\mathrm{Re}(a) = \frac{a+a^*}{2}$  and $\mathrm{Im}(a) = \frac{a-a^*}{2i}$ are selfadjoint.

Hence, for all $a \in A$ we obtain
$$ \phi(a^*) = \phi(\mathrm{Re}(a)-i\mathrm{Im}(a)) = \phi(\mathrm{Re}(a)) - i\phi(\mathrm{Im}(a)) = \overline{\phi(\mathrm{Re}(a)) + i\phi(\mathrm{Im}(a))} = \overline{\phi(a)}.$$

Comment: The proof is verbatim the same for unital positive maps between C*-algebras: they satisfy $\phi(x^*) = \phi(x)^*$.